# How do I "sum" a column with categorical vairables in R?

Tags: r, grouping, categorical-data

I am trying to create a figure and in order to do that I need to group certain categories together while maintaining certain columns.

Here is an example of my data:

```
plot   species         species_group   tally_95   tally_19
ba11   A. rubrum         acer            937.5     625.0
ba11   A. saccharum      acer            312.5     837.2
ba11   Q. alba           quercus         312.5     1250.4 
ba11   Fraxinus sp.      fraxinus        0.0       1875.1
ba12   A. rubrum         acer            312.5     3437.5
ba12   A. arborea        shade_tol       625.0     1562.5
ba12   C. canadensis     shade_tol       2500.0    5000.0
ba13   S. albidum        sassafras       3750.0    2812.5
```

This is what I would like my data to look like:

```
species_group   tally_95   tally_19
acer            1562.5     4899.7
quercus         312.5      1250.4
fraxinus        0.0        1875.1
shade_tol       3125.0     6562.5
sassafras       3750.0     2812.5
```

I just want to be able to group by species_group across all of my plots. I've tried aggregate() but it only uses numerical variables. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `aggregate(cbind(tally_95, tally_19)~species_group, df, sum)` Or using `dplyr` , `df %>%
  group_by(species_group) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with('tally')), sum)`

Comment: @RonakShah that worked. Thank you so much!